# Find the prime factorization in the DLP

Tags: discrete-logarithm

Suppose we have $g^x \equiv h \pmod N$ Where $N = pq$ and $p$, $q$ are distinct primes. Also $(p-1)/2$ and $(q-1)/2$ are primes.

If we know what $x$, $g$ and $h$ are, is it possible for us to know what $p$ and $q$ are? 
I'm trying to find out but I'm running into closed doors.

I tried the following:

 $gcd(p-1 , q-1) = 2$
$g^{(p-1)(q-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$

so $1 \equiv h^{(p-1)(q-1)/2} \pmod {pq}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the question "If we know what $x$, $g$ and $h$ are, is it possible for us to know what $p$ and $q$ are?", I doubt there is a positive answer $\;$ However _another_ interesting question is: "If we knew a method to find $x$ such that $ g^x\equiv h\pmod N$ given $(g,h)$, would it be possible for us to know what $p$ and $q$ are?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, suppose we pick a random $h$, and compute $g = h^3 \bmod N$.  We then find the minimal value $x$ where $g^x \equiv h \pmod{N}$ (and, yes, such an $x$ will exist, assuming $p, q > 7$).

What can we deduce from such a value of $x$?

Comment: For this to work, $x$ must be $-3 \pmod {\phi (N)}$ right?

Comment: @mikerussel: Actually, $3^{-1}$, not $-3$.

Comment: Okay so how does this help us retrieve $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @mikerussel: What is $3x-1 \bmod {(p-1)(q-1)/2}$ with good probability?

Comment: We know $x = 3^{-1}$ so $3x-1= 0$ So $(p-1)(q-1)/2$ divides $3x-1$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write $3x -1$ divides $(p-1)(q-1)/2$. I'm still failing to understand how this relates to finding $p$ and $q$ though

Comment: @mikerussel: no, your first statement was correct; there exists an integer $k$ such that $3x-1 = k(p-1)(q-1)/2$.  Now, how big can $k$ be?  Hint: $x < (p-1)(q-1)/2$, as it's the minimal $x$ value.

Comment: $k$ cannot be bigger than $3$ right?

Comment: But the question which remains: how easy is to find such h satisfying $g=h^3 \; mod \; N$ ?

Comment: @RobertNACIRI: I assumed that this was the question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/n-pq-be-a-product-of-distinct-primes-p-and-q (asked better); there, we assume that, given $g$ and $h$, we can find $x$ (and are asked to show that that implies an easy factorization method)

Comment: @poncho, Ah, OK, I didn't made the connection.

Comment: @mikerussel, if k can't be bigger than 3, what are the admissible values ? what could we deduce then?

Comment: @RobertNACIRI: actually, I misspoke; it's $3x-1 \bmod (p-1)(q-1)/4$ which is 0 with high probability.  In any case, if we have a value $k(pq-p-q+1)/4$ (for modest $k$), and $pq$, how can we rederive $p, q$?

Comment: @poncho, in this exceptionnal case, we could test for the divisibility of $3.x-1$ for successive small values of k, and then solving the system gives p+q.
I'm wondering also if you couldn't manage better by using quadratic residues. With the given form of p and q, $-1 \in QR(p)\cdots QR(q) \cdots QR(pq)$

Comment: Sorry for the typo: Understand $QNR$

Answer (score 0):

Just knowing *any* such triple would not help at all. Reason:

Choose $g$ and $x$ arbitrarily, calculate $h$. Now you got such a triple, but it shouldn't help you factorize $N$, unless you have another interesting property.

If on the other hand you can somehow calculate roots (given $x$ and $h$, and then find $g$), then you can break RSA: Choose $x=e$, and your root algorithm finds the plaintext to a ciphertext.

If you can find square roots (and there are always 4 of them with $n=pq$), then you can actually factorize $N$, the attack basically works like the chosen ciphertext attack on  [Rabins encryption scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem): Choose $a$, calculate $a^2$, apply your algorithm to $a^2$ to find a square root. Since it only has $a^2$ as input, it will result in one of the four square roots, but not necessarily the one you started with. If the result is not $a$ or $-a$, then you can factorize $N$.